# Converting file sessions to database-based sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm trying to convert normal, file-based sessions to more manageable database-based sessions, thus giving me greater flexibility in terms of scaling, and managing sessions, including remotely terminating them.

This is the current login process:

```
                if($db)//$u&&$p)
                    {                           

                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE ";
                        switch(LOGIN_METHOD)
                            {
                                case 'both':
                                    $sql .= "(username='".$db->real_escape_string($u)."' OR useremail='".mysql_real_escape_string($u)."')";
                                    break;
                                case 'email':
                                    $sql .= "useremail='".$db->real_escape_string($u)."'";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    $sql .= "username='".$db->real_escape_string($u)."'";
                                    break;
                            }
                        $sql .= " AND userpassword = '".md5($sysconfig['salt'].$p)."'";

                        $rs = @$db->query($sql);

                        if(!$rs) return false;

                        if($rs->num_rows)
                            {
                                $this->set_session(array_merge($rs->fetch_assoc(),array('expires'=>time()+(15*60))));
                                $return = true;
                            }
                        $rs->free_result();
                        $db->close();
                        unset($rs,$sql);
                    }
```

The line I am interested in, where it sets the session is:

```
$this->set_session(array_merge($rs->fetch_assoc(),array('expires'=>time()+(15*60))));
```

Where, set_session:

```
private function set_session($a=false)
    {
        if(!empty($a))
            {
                $_SESSION['exp_user'] = $a;
            }
    }
```

In the table, only the username, login email, login password and userid is stored.

How would I go about converting this to a database-based session system, powered by MySQL, of course?

Should I go with MEMORY or HEAP type tables?

Comment: Ideally you'd only touch the database when the session is started or closed, and otherwise just deal with $_SESSION as you would otherwise. The table type depends on how much traffic you're expecting - memory tables won't work if you've got clustered servers and/or huge numbers of users.

Comment: You may also want to consider using Memcache based sessions.

Comment: I'm afraid you don't fully understand what is session db handler and how it should work. Please look on this tutorial: http://www.nateklaiber.com/blog/2006/05/10/custom-php-session-handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at [`set_session_save_handler`](http://php.net/session_set_save_handler). It allows you to specify how the session handler can retrieve and store it's data. It's fairly straightforward to write an implementation that uses a database.

With this approach you can continue to use `$_SESSION` like you normally would.

`MEMORY` and `HEAP` is the same thing (in MySQL). You can chose to use a `MEMORY` table since sessions are allowed to be volatile. I don't know much about the performance characteristics for this purpose though. I'm guessing that if your session table is small enough it will be mostly in memory anyway.

Comment: I assume I'd use `session_id()` as some sort of key?

Comment: Would you be able to give me further guidance, i.e when to write the session to the database. Also, how would destroying the data kill the session?

Comment: The session will be written to the database when you want it to. The write and close handler seem like good options.

Comment: `read`, `save` and `delete` will supply your function with an `$id`. Read the documentation.